# How to update one column in table from select statement?

Tags: sql-server, update

I have a table that looks like this:

```
utc date                       est date
2018-03-01 07:06:38.000
2018-03-01 07:07:38.000
```

`est date` is blank. I have a select statement that calculates EST time.

How do i update the `est date` column from my select statement?

```
SELECT toCONVERT(datetime, 
               SWITCHOFFSET(CONVERT(datetimeoffset, 
                                    table."utc date"), 
                            DATENAME(TzOffset, SYSDATETIMEOFFSET())))
       as "etc date"
FROM table where  "utc date" > '2017-10-01'
```

Comment: This should be a basic update statement from select like [so.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2334741/1532495)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[UPDATE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) syntax:

```
UPDATE [table]
SET [est date] = toCONVERT(datetime, 
                           SWITCHOFFSET(CONVERT(datetimeoffset, table.[utc date]), 
                           DATENAME(TzOffset, SYSDATETIMEOFFSET())))
WHERE [utc date] > '2017-10-01'
```